# Cant copy properities of one class to another using BeanUtils

Tags: java, class, copy, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a piece of code where I copy the similar properities of one class to another using `BeanUtils.copyProperities(dest, orig)`. However. This does not work. I get the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory`

I am using BeanUtils 1.9.2, Java 8, Windows 10, Eclipse.

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.*;

public class Main{
    public Main(){
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        AbstractGameObject aEntity = new AbstractGameObject();
        try {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(aEntity, entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(aEntity.similar); // Should print out 10, No?;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
    }
    private class Entity{
        int similar = 10;
        int differentE = 9;
        public Entity(){

        }
    }
    private class AbstractGameObject{
        int similar = 2;
        int differentA = 1;
        public AbstractGameObject(){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add commons-logging library to classpath http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Of course, `BeanUtils` uses `Common-logging` (and `commons-collections`), If you are using maven, gradle or similar, It'll get BeanUtils's dependencies for you, but if you aren't, you must to add beanUtils's dependencias to classpath manually.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Thanks, Stops the error. The function does not seem to preform properly however, as I am getting 2 instead of 10 as an answer. Nethertheless, if you post a proper answer, I will accept and upvote it as you have solved my problem.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Still dosent work. Still get the number 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important: classes must be public and copyProperties uses setters and getters.
Try with:

```
public class Main {
    public Main()  {
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        AbstractGameObject aEntity = new AbstractGameObject();

        try {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(aEntity, entity);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // use a logger
        }
        System.out.println(aEntity.similar);
        System.out.println(entity.similar);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main main = new Main();
    }

    public class Entity {

        private int similar = 10;
        private int differentE = 9;

        public int getSimilar() {
            return similar;
        }

        public void setSimilar(int similar) {
            this.similar = similar;
        }

        public int getDifferentE() {
            return differentE;
        }

        public void setDifferentE(int differentE) {
            this.differentE = differentE;
        }        

    }

    public  class AbstractGameObject {

        private int similar = 2;
        private int differentA = 1;

        public int getSimilar() {
            return similar;
        }

        public void setSimilar(int similar) {
            this.similar = similar;
        }

        public int getDifferentA() {
            return differentA;
        }

        public void setDifferentA(int differentA) {
            this.differentA = differentA;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This code still dosent work, I get the error ---`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap`

Comment: @Colourfit did you add `commons-collections` library to classpath?? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/

Comment: `BeanUtils` version 1.9.2  uses `commons-collections` version 3.2.1. Are you use the right version?

Comment: @Colourfit Maven(or gradle) will be your friend.

Answer (score 3):

Also, just a note that `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` will not work if you use Lombok to generate your public getters and setters. You must manually create them.